# AWS Automatic IAM Roles for Service Users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have an EC2 instance that has an assigned/assumed role. When I run:

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

as the main login user or with `sudo` it returns the account information expected. However, I have a service which uses AWS that runs under a different user (`prometheus`). Its log indicates failure to get a role. Additionally, when I run the following I get a failure:

```
sudo -u prometheus aws sts get-caller-identity
```

Which user accounts have access to the assumed role? How do we get additional users to have access to the assumed role? (it is clearly not just an issue of being a service since `sudo -u` doesn't work either).

If it matters, the system is Rocky 8. There are no directories `/root/.aws` or `/home/rocky/.aws`. The bash environment has no `AWS_*` values.

Comment: I have also tried setting up the server user's .aws/credentials file and it doesn't like the credentials